# Quit function on body onLoad

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I need a script thats redirects the user to a second side, when the mainpage need to long to load.

I did this:

```
 <script type='text/javascript'>   
    $(document).ready(function() {
    setTimeout("location.replace('contact.html')",10000);
    });
</script>
```

To sametime a preloader opens an get hided on on body onload, when that happens i need to kill the functon above?

Anybody an idea?

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
var redirect = setTimeout(function(){
                  window.location = 'somewhere'
               }, 10000)

$(document).ready(function() { // or $(window).load(function() {
    clearTimeout(redirect);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  setTimeout("location.replace('contact.html')",10000);
```

Instead, you can try

```
  setTimeout(function(){window.location='contact.html'},10000);
```

Answer (score 0):

You Can try Following

```
var Ispreloader=false;

    <script type='text/javascript'>   
        $(document).ready(function() {
         if(!Ispreloader)
         {
           myfunction();
          }

        });

function myfunction()
{
  setTimeout("location.replace('contact.html')",10000);
}

//------------Whenever preploadeer loads on bodu unload set the variable to true

Ispreloader=true;
 </script>
```